# Python pandas json_normalized a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a pd.json_normalized on a dataframe but it results into an empty dataframe.

initial dataframe
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGphv.png)

after applying json_normalized,

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(df)
print(df1)
```

it became an empty dataframe. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/733Dx.png)

when I tried to define the dataframe manually using below, I got my expected output

```
data = [
    {'birthday': '542217600000', 'first_name': 'Char', 'gender': 'Male', 'last_name': 'Mander', 'nick_name': ''},
    {'birthday': '967046400000', 'first_name': 'ABC', 'gender': 'Male', 'last_name': 'ZXY', 'nick_name': ''},
    {'birthday': '739900800000', 'first_name': 'Test', 'gender': 'Male', 'last_name': 'tickles', 'nick_name': ''}
]

birthday = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=1)
print(birthday)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB2th.png)

May I know how can I directly normalized from a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a Series to [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), not a Dataframe:

```
# your initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'properties': data})

# passing the relevant column/Series
birthday = pd.json_normalize(df['properties'], max_level=1)
```

Output:

```
       birthday first_name gender last_name nick_name
0  542217600000       Char   Male    Mander          
1  967046400000        ABC   Male       ZXY          
2  739900800000       Test   Male   tickles
```

Comment: thank you but I was not able to mention that the initial dataframe im using is from a csv file. I used this code to load

with open (input1 ,'r') as data1:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(data1, encoding='utf-8', dtype= 'object', sep=',')

then running json normalized provided me this error code
line 461, in _json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 461, in <genexpr>
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: can you provide the content of the csv file for debugging?

Comment: cardinality|create_time|properties
382|2022-04-05 16:32:43.000+0000|{'birthday': '542217600000', 'first_name': 'Char', 'gender': 'Male', 'last_name': 'Mander', 'nick_name': ''}
400|2022-02-07 14:20:59.000+0000|{'birthday': '967046400000', 'first_name': 'ABC', 'gender': 'Male', 'last_name': 'ZXY', 'nick_name': ''}
132|2021-08-09 14:01:30.000+0000|{'birthday': '739900800000', 'first_name': 'Test', 'gender': 'Male', 'last_name': 'Tickles', 'nick_name': ''}

Comment: Complete steps im doing:
1. with open (input1 ,'r') as data1: df1 = pd.read_csv(data1, encoding='utf-8', dtype= 'object', sep=',') 
2. df1=df1['properties']
3. pd.json_normalized(df1)

Comment: Can you add these details directly in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Note that calling dict() on a pd.DataFrame does not result in a valid JSON object, therefore you need a workaround, e.g.:

```
regular_json = [row[1].to_dict() for row  in df.iterrows()]
pd.json_normalize(regular_json)
```